# Using scripting to test a program

Tags: testing, scripting

I've been tasked with testing a Windows program that is essentially a collection of links to various exe files. My job is basically to click all the links to make sure they work (yay!). To makes things a bit easier on myself, I want to create a simple script that will do the clicking for me. I have a programming background (familiar with C/C++, Java), but have never scripted anything before.

Despite googling and searching around on stackoverflow, I wasn't able to find anything that explains what would be involved in creating something like this. I downloaded a program called AutoHotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) that seems promising, but before I dive into it I want to see what suggestions you all have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried autohotkey so I can't give you feedback. But I played around a bit with [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) which is agnostic of the UI technology used (working with image recognition). It works fine and you should be able to come up with a working prototype in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

HP Unified Functional Testing (http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/unified-functional-testing-automated-testing/) provides similar functionality as Sikuli. As licensed software, it isn't free, but provides a lot more features and support than Sikuli (which is open source) does.